# Error: Cannot import name 'url_encode' when installing Apache Superset on Ubuntu

Tags: sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I have been trying Apache Superset installation for 2 weeks now.
Every time I start a fresh Installation some new error pops up.
I tried on windows and then I gave up.
Now for few days I have been trying on linux. 
There is no correct Documentation to install superset.
All the documents or suggestions or installation guide are just same.
It is so annoying..Argh!!
Anyway I tried " superset db upgrade" and I get the following error.
Also If anyone has the correct requirement.txt with version of each lib 
please share it will be very usefull.
I am using ubuntu 18.04 and python version is 3.6.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 5, in <module>
    from superset.cli import create_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/superset/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, IndexView, SQLA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder.baseviews import BaseView
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .forms import GeneralModelConverter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_wtf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .recaptcha import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .fields import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import widgets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py", line 5, in <module>
    from werkzeug import url_encode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode'
```

Comment: If you're stalling on installing superset, you have a couple of alternatives: 1. try the docker container version, or 2. Use a managed superset instance such as preset.io or duperset.com

Comment: If you are trying install using windows please use this guide - https://gist.github.com/Jamesvasanth21/49b33c2c0c61519f4e8bdb67cc54532d

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely the install of the package that failed in the beginning. it seems you did not create a virtual env to install superset. it is recommended to do so. did you do the following ?

```
pip install virtualenv
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
pip install apache-superset
```

Any errors during doing so ?

Comment: can you copy/paste the exact command you are trying to execute (including the bash) ? can you do a pip freeze and copy paste the output ?